# How to make use of join in linq having multiple tables and use orderby?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need some help, i have a one working join, need the other one for third table? How can i create it? My orderby does not work either with year and need some help also. This is my logic as below and using Linq in sql;

```
 // controller
      public IList<ExtractionViewModel> GetExtractionViewModels()
            {
                ProductionManagementEntities db = new ProductionManagementEntities();
    
                var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays
                                    join w in db.Weeks on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId
// need other join here for the second table
                                    orderby w.Year ascending // this is not working, year starts in 2017 instead of 2021 downwards
                                    where(w.WeekNum == 9)
                                    
                                  
                                    select new ExtractionViewModel
                                  {
    
                                   Year = w.Year,
                                   Week = w.WeekNum,
                                   Day = p.ProductionDate,
    
    
    
                                    }).ToList();
                return scheduleList;
            }
```

Comment: not sure exactly from your wording of the question, but it sounds like you want descending not ascending

Comment: @Keith the year is descending not ascending

Comment: Everything works fine. You have to use  orderby w.Year descending if you want to see 2021,2020,2019 and so on

Comment: @Sergy yes, now is it possible to add another table using from m.db.table then join after? i have tried that but return empty records now im stuck

Answer (score 0):

```
// Model
  public class ExtractionViewModel
    {
        public string Year { get; set; }

        public int Week { get; set; }

        public DateTime Day { get; set; }

        public string VW250 { get; set; }

        public string VW270 { get; set; }

        public string VW250_2PA { get; set; }

        public string VW_270_PA { get; set; }
    }

//Controller 


public IList<ExtractionViewModel> GetExtractionViewModels()
        {
            ProductionManagementEntities db = new ProductionManagementEntities();

            var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays
                                from m in db.Models
                                join w in db.Weeks on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId
                                orderby w.Year descending
                                orderby m.Name ascending
                                where(m.Name== "VW250")
                                where(w.WeekNum == 9)
                                
                              
                                select new ExtractionViewModel
                              {

                                Year = w.Year,
                               Week = w.WeekNum,
                               Day = p.ProductionDate,
                               VW250 = m.Name


                                }).ToList();
            return scheduleList;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Linq query, this should work:

```
var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays
                    join w in db.Weeks on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId
                    join n in db.NewTable on p.WeekId equals n.WeekId
                    where w.WeekNum equals 9 and m.Name equals "VW250"
                    orderby w.Year ascending
                    select new ExtractionViewModel
                    {
                        Year = w.Year,
                        Week = w.WeekNum,
                        Day = p.ProductionDate,
                        Property = n.Property
                    }).ToList();
```

A simpler way, and also seems to run a bit quicker as well, is:

```
var scheduleList = db.ProductionDays
                   .Include(x => x.Weeks)
                   .Include(x => x.NewTable)
                   .Where(x => x.Week.WeekNum == 9)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.Week.Year)
                   .Select(x => new ExtractionViewModel {
                         x.Week.Year,
                         x.Week.WeekNum,
                         x.ProductionDate,
                         x.NewTable.Property
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

The second one is linq method and when debugging and stepping through I notice that they seem to be quicker than linq queries.

The problem with your query seemed to be the syntax on the `where` clause. You had `where(w.WeekNum == 9)` which may work but I have never seen that syntax. With linq, I have only worked with lambda expressions or `where property equals value` type syntax. I haven't tested this so if there is an error you will probably need to move the `.OrderBy()` statement to the bottom, but it should be fine.

In the question you don't mention what third table you would like to `join` but indicate that there is a third table. I added `NewTable` and `NewTable.Property` to indicate the third table and one of its columns/Properties.